# Como comparar um array vetor com uma coluna transformada em array (linha a linha)

Tags: python, array

Estou tentando relacionar um vetor array (intitulado df) com uma coluna de um bd que possui vários valores separados por virgula em str. Quero que primeiramente o código analise somente linhas cuja classificação seja 'Doce'. Caso seja classificado como "doce", quero que ele vá até a coluna "Tipo", converta os valores em array e armazene numa variável. Posterior a isso, quero fazer uma comparação entre esses valores armazenados como array com o vetor (df). Se houver pelo menos um valor compatível com df, quero que retorne na coluna vazia que criei denominando 'Classificação'.

Quando executo meu código, o mesmo retorna apenas 'Abacaxi' em todas as linhas da coluna 'Classificação', ainda que existam valores que o classificariam como "Morango".

Abaixo estão recortes das bases que usei.

BD:

```
Categoria  Data     Tipo         Classificação  
   Doce   05/01   111,222,555                 
 Salgado  03/02   999,888,000
 Salgado  03/02   999       
   Doce   05/01   222,333 
   Doce   07/01   444     
   Doce   07/01   888,999
```

Esta foi a tentativa mais recente:

```
bd['Classificação'] = ''
df = ['111',
      '222',
      '333',
      '444',
     `'555']
df= np.array(df)

linhas = bd.loc[bd['Categoria'] == 'Doce'] #Comando para que o programa trabalhe apenas nas linhas em que a categoria seja 'Doce'.
array = []
coluna = bd['Tipos']

for i in linhas:
  for item in coluna:
   array = np.array(coluna) #Transformar as informações da coluna em array para comparação com o df    
    if array == df:
      bd['Classificação'] = 'Morango'
    else:
      bd['Classificação'] = 'Abacaxi'
```

Alguém sabe o que há de errado com o meu código?

Comment: Você está comparando se o vetor é igual, não se o item está no vetor. Por isso vai tudo pro else, abacaxi.

Comment: Aqui `linhas = bd['Categoria'] == 'Doce'` você diz ser *o o comando para que o programa trabalhe apenas nas linhas em que a categoria seja 'Doce'*. Acho que você quer fazer isso `linhas = bd.loc[bd['Categoria'] == 'Doce']` .Vou prosseguir analisando o seu código.

Comment: Obrigada, Augusto! Irei realizar a atualização em meu código.

Comment: @DanielIkenaga entendo, estive pesquisando formas de realizar a comparação por itens (ex Set &) e até onde entendi, estou tendo dificuldades em fazer essa comparação porque df é 1d, enquanto bd é 2d, mas como por vezes não sei quantos itens ocorrem em cada linha de ''Tipos'', não sei como fazer essa conversão em 2d. Estou travada. Saberia alguma forma de executar essa ação? Inclusive, devo adicionar esse comentário a publicação inicial?